# Error in : Clipboard on X11 requires that the DISPLAY envvar be configured

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shinyapp in which I would like to put an actionbutton to copy some code (I'm using shinyace). 
When I run my app for the first time, on a new session, it works fine. But when I close it and run it again, I've got an error :

```
Error in : Clipboard on X11 requires that the DISPLAY envvar be configured
```

I installed the `xclip` and `xsel` but the problem still exists. When I deploy my app with Shinyapps.io, I'm disconnected each time I want to use the copy-to-clipboard function.

Here are my `sessionInfo()` and `capabilities()` :

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rsconnect_0.8.13 clipr_0.6.0      shinyAce_0.4.0   shiny_1.3.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1      packrat_0.5.0   digest_0.6.20   later_0.8.0     bitops_1.0-6   
 [6] mime_0.7        R6_2.4.0        jsonlite_1.6    xtable_1.8-4    magrittr_1.5   
[11] rlang_0.4.0     rstudioapi_0.10 promises_1.0.1  tools_3.6.1     RCurl_1.95-4.12
[16] httpuv_1.5.1    compiler_3.6.1  askpass_1.1     htmltools_0.3.6 openssl_1.4
```

```
jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE 
     libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE
```

Do you know how to solve this problem ?

I also asked here : https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-clipboard-on-x11-requires-that-the-display-envvar-be-configured/34894

Comment: Hey! Did you solve the problem?

Comment: not yet, I have quickly tried to use the answer below but no success (I didn't search deeply though)

Comment: I'm not sure why the DISPLAY var has changed inside R but when I do `Sys.setenv(DISPLAY = ":0")`, it works. In a terminal, running `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using xclip in a custom function as I do not know how to pass the `DISPLAY` var to `clipr::write_clip()`:

```
clipboard<-function(x, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=F){
  con <- pipe("xclip -selection clipboard -i  -display :1", open="w") # note the 1 here
  #writeChar(x, con)  # for strings
  write.table(x, con, sep=sep, row.names=row.names, col.names=col.names) # for table
  close(con)
}
```

My experience is: my rstudio server must use the display that the linux terminal uses.

When I put in the **linux terminal**

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

gives me `:1` and this works:

```
echo 1235 | xclip -sel clip
```

But inside Rstudio-server, in its system terminal `$DISPLAY` gives me `:0` and xclip line fails. It only works in RStudio-server after changing to `DISPLAY=:1` in RStudio-server system terminal or with the `-display` flag in the above function

The fact that the first time you use it, works, make me suggest to use a counter to increase the number of the display each time and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
```

after calling libs.